# Updating PresentationMode value for child view from parent

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want update **presentationMode** with environment modifier to update childView, in the parent view presentationMode key asks for a Binding to **PresentationMode** I also made that, but the Xcode does not help to make the code get fixed, here what I tried so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var presentationMode: PresentationMode

    var body: some View {

        MyTestView()
            .environment(\.presentationMode, $presentationMode)
        
        Button("update") {
            
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented.toggle()
        }
 
    }
}

struct MyTestView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented { Text("Hello, world!") }
        
    }
}
```

error 1:

> Key path value type 'WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Binding>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Binding>'

error 2:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'isPresented' is a get-only property

I do not think error2 should be happen because presentationMode is a State in parent view!

Comment: What actually you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It is *read-only* environment value, we cannot modify it - only read

```
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension EnvironmentValues {

    /// A binding to the current presentation mode of the view associated with
    /// this environment.
    @available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use isPresented or dismiss")
    @available(macOS, introduced: 10.15, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use isPresented or dismiss")
    @available(tvOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use isPresented or dismiss")
    @available(watchOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use isPresented or dismiss")
    public var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode> { get }  // << here !!
}
```